# jquery dialog and user control

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

How do i make the jquery dialog to cover only on the user control not the entire page.. any ideas?

Imagine that i have this script on the user control (.ascx)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#popup").dialog({ closeOnEscape: false, draggable: false, modal: true, 
                                resizable: false, closeText: 'hide' });

    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "xml",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "Service2.svc/DoWork",
            data: "{}",
            processdata: true, //True or False
            success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                $("#popup").dialog('close');

            },
            error: function () {
                $("#popup").dialog('close');
                alert("error");
            }
        });
});

</script>

<div id="popup" style="display:none">
Loading contents... 
</div>
```

Now, the problem is when the user control is loaded the modal (overlay) covers the entire page. I want it to cover just on the user control only so the user is still be able to interact with the other controls on the page.

Comment: I have a user control and within that user control I have a javascript that implements jquery UI dialog. Now when the modal is set true and it covers the entire page. How do i make it to cover just on the user control only?

Comment: @user384080 - Can you post your code. Without it, it is difficult to tell what exactly you are using and how you are using it.

Comment: How can i post my code here? it does not have the feature to upload file..

Comment: Copy and paste the relevant sections. Use the `{}` button on the editor so it will appear correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only want to block a certain part of the page, don't use modal, do it manually. Wrap the part of the page you want to disable in a div, and add/remove the overlay in the dialog's open and close events.

```
$("#popup").dialog({
    closeOnEscape: false,
    draggable: false,
    modal: false,
    resizable: false,
    closeText: 'hide',
    open: function(){
        $('.coverme').append('<div class="ui-widget-overlay"></div>');
    },
    close: function(){
        $('.coverme').find('.ui-widget-overlay').remove();
    }        
});
```

In the code above, `'.coverme'` is the selector which selects the parts of the page you want to dim and block. Make sure that you set the containers' `position` css property to relative or absolute (anything but static), otherwise the overlay will fill the whole page.

Have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/DBd36/

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI's `dialog` allows you to [specify a position](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-position), so you can position it wherever you want, including "on the user control":

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({ position: [10, 200], height: 300, width: 300 });
```